# Print sub categories list with categories in JSON response

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-boot

I have mysql table like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON3JL.png

this is entity class for this table

```
Where(clause = "active =1")
@Entity
@Table(name = "category", catalog = "businessin")
public class Category implements java.io.Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer parentId;
    private Integer active;
    private String pic;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

    setters&getter 
}
```

I'm building RESTful API using spring rest and spring data (jpaRepositories) 
I want when printing main categories from controllers as JSON reponse i want them to have also a list of subCategories
example for this

```
[
{
id: 1,
name: "Electronics",
parentId: 0,
active: 1,
pic: null
}]
```

to this

```
[
{
id: 1,
name: "Electronics",
parentId: 0,
active: 1,
pic: null
subCategories: [Mobile, Laptops]
}]
```

Comment: I think you need to change your "Integer parentId", to "Category parent".  Then you need to make a relationship (OneToMany perhaps) to List<Category> subCategories, mapped by the parent.

Comment: good suggestion but not working  , Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.parent] of basic type  ,and exception in the repository @DaShaun

Comment: Ahh, so, perhaps change Category parent back to Integer, and make that your "mapped by" instead.  The null.parent is because Electronics doesn't have a parent.

Comment: this error appears when just spring create the database

Comment: So @ManyToOne on Category parent.  (I realize I need to improve my skills here, I'm just trying to help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's simple make your entity like this

```
@Where(clause = "active =1")
@Entity
@Table(name = "category" )
public class Category implements java.io.Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable=false,columnDefinition="int default 1")
    private Integer active;
    private String pic;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
       @JsonIgnore
   // @ColumnDefault("0")
    private Category parentId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentId")
    private List<Category> subCategories=new ArrayList<>();

setters and getters

}
```